# Are Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat repositories going to be removed or deleted after April 10-2012?

Tags: 10.10, official-repositories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat and i would like to know if the repositories of this Ubuntu version are going to be removed or deleted from the main servers after April 10 (that's the day when Ubuntu 10.10's life ends) or if only there will be no more updates.

Thank you very much =)